# Find the values of $k$ that make this system inconsistent, with unique solution, and with infinite solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I've learned to find the solutions to linear systems using Gaussian Elimination. Moving on, I've found a new kind of exercise I hadn't done before:

> Find the values for $k$ that make this system:
>
> - Inconsistent (no solutions)
> - With unique solution
> - With infinite solutions $$\begin {cases} kx + y + z = 1\\ x + ky + z = 1\\ x + y + kz = 1 \end {cases}$$

Let's see...

---

### For inconsistency

If I wanted this system to be inconsistent, I would need a row to be of the form $0 + 0 + 0 = 1$... But even if $k = 0$, I would also need two of the three $x,y,z$ variables to also be $0$ to have such a row, which is not necessarily true. So what then?

---

### For unique solution

For unique solution, I would need tha rank of the matrix to be $3$. I think that in this case, it is enough to say $k = 1$, because it would cause the diagonal to be a bunch of $1$s, and I *think* there was a theorem saying that when this happens the matrix can always be reduced to the identity, thus having an unique solution. I'm not sure how to word this though.

---

### For infinite solutions

For infinite solutions, the rank of the matrix has to be less than $3$... and I'm not even sure how to proceed.

Comment: Firstly, if the determinant is not zero, then you have unique solutions. if the determinant is zero however...think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: The determinant is:

$$k^3-3 k+2 = (k-1)^2(k+2) = 0 \implies k = 1, -2$$

We want the determinant to be nonzero for unique solutions.

If we substitute $k = 1$ in the system, and do a RREF we have:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

If we substitute $k = -2$ in the system, and do a RREF we have:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Can you now derive conclusions for inconsistent, unique solution and infinite solutions?

Comment: Nice hints and leading question!